# json path returning an extra [ ] in soapui

Tags: json, soapui, jsonpath

I want to extract the value of profileId based on the profile type property from below json response.

There can be multiple profile type and their ids and i want one whose profile type is OLB.

I created this json path-

`$.signees[*].signeeProfile[?(@.profileType=='OLB')].profileId`

this is returning me [[117309]] whereas I need [117309].

Please help to correct the json path.
[image: json resonse]

[image: property transfer step in soap Ui]

Comment: Have you tried `$.signees[*].signeeProfile[?(@.profileType=='OLB')].profileId[0]` ?

Comment: oh! this worked. Silly mistake. Thanks much @ou_ryperd